# Which docker image to use for static image storage?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, upload, nestjs, static-files

I'm developing a full stack application, using Angular, NestJS and docker. The PostgreSQL database and NestJS backend are running in docker containers, using docker-compose.

The application must allow the user to upload images and other types of files. There must be control over which images should be public or not. Some images will be used in the frontend.

I would like to use only my application's own resources. I wouldn't want to store images on S3, for example.

One option would be to save the images directly to storage using Muter or fs. But I prefer to do this in a separate location.

I was wondering if it wouldn't be better to create a file server, cdn, or something similar using docker-compose.

The problem is that I don't know what would be the best option. Which docker images should I use?

I would also like something that is easy to test through unit testing and integration testing using jest.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to use an open source, S3 compatible cloud storage system. MinIO uses the same API as S3 and can run inside a docker container. Maybe I'll use the NodeJS file system for exclusively public files too.

```yaml
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      # Only will build development stage from our dockerfile
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      # This is the only change
    env_file:
      - .env
      # Run a command against the development stage of the image
    command: npm run start:debug
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
      - ${SERVER_DEBUG_PORT}:${SERVER_DEBUG_PORT}
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - minio
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:12
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE_NAME}
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}
    hostname: ${DB_HOST}
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
  minio:
    container_name: minio
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - "${MINIO_PORT}:${MINIO_PORT}"
      - "${MINIO_CONSOLE_PORT}:${MINIO_CONSOLE_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - minio_storage:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_USER}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - webnet
    command: server --console-address ":${MINIO_CONSOLE_PORT}" /data
networks:
  webnet:
volumes:
  pgdata:
  minio_storage: {}
```